# How to remove 'View Entire Message' option in gmail sent using sendgrid

Tags: gmail

In my current project, we are sending some user chosen services to the mail address provided in input.

We are using a HTML file to format the services and copying this html template to 'mail.Body' before sending the email.
The emails are sent using Sendgrid

When recieving this in gmail ,only for some clients (Set-A) ,even for short email '[Message clipped]  View entire message' is shown at the bottom of the email.

We use similar html template to send it for different clients(Set -B), but '[Message clipped]  View entire message' is **NOT DISPLAYED** in this mail ,even when the email is longer.

Tried minified HTML template , but still 'View entire message' is shown at bottom of gmail for only Set-A clients.

The HTML file size before copying to mail body for Set-A (40.11KB) is smaller than that of Set-B (49.09KB).

So I am assuming size is not the problem for this

I compared both the HMTL templates, no difference in styles or other HTML tags. Just the text content is different.

Kindly advise how to avoid this 'View Entire message' option being displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me it had to do with the character set of the email body. Email body "Hej på dig!" and "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" would reproduce the bug.

You need to make sure that the email body is indeed encoded as declared (check using "show original"). After converting the body from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 the problem went away.